# Slim php csrf failed

Tags: php, file, csv, slim-3

I've got a controller action which output's CSV file using league/csv package.
When I post the form the file can be downloaded but if the post request is posted again I'm getting csrf token failed which is correct because csrf code is expiring after every request. What is the best way to redirect page after file download in Slim framework PHP

```
     $csv = \League\Csv\Writer::createFromFileObject(new \SplTempFileObject());

    Data::where('user_id','=',$user_id)->get()->each(function($dat) use($csv) {
        $data = $dat->toArray();
        $data['link'] = $dat->getLink();
        $csv->insertOne($data);
    });
     $csv->output('data.csv');
```

Comment: you can use a simple redirect header like so `header("location:urltoredirectto.php");`

Comment: Why do you need to check for as CSRF token after a redirect?

Comment: what are you retuning at the end of your controller ?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved. I made ajax request which returned csrf token and csv file content. 
and i used below code to download file using javascript

```
var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=UTF-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csvdata);
                window.open(uri, 'data.csv');
```